# GETPIVOTDATA() -- less than date

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("amount",$A$3,"state",A6,"issueDate",(DATE(2011,11,30)-365*M6))
```

Trying to select everything where the `issueDate` is less than the formula value for a date.

Answer (score 0):

I think that GetPivotData only matches to one, and only one, item, subtotal or total visible somewhere in the pivot table.  It therefore can't be used to summarize a range of items directly.  Instead, the date range needs to be specified in the pivot table itself, so that GetPivotData can pick it up as an item, subtotal or total.